# Obtener información de objeto JSON con Fetch

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de obtener la información de una API que muestra los resultados de eventos sísmicos ocurridos durante las ultimas horas en el país, pero no logro mostrar el resultado en una tabla.
Estoy realizando la solicitud mediante el método Fetch con JS.

```
let url =
  "https://chilealerta.com/api/query/?user=demo&select=ultimos_sismos_chile";
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => mostrarData(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

const mostrarData = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  let html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += `
    <tr>
      <td>${data[i].ultimos_sismos_chile.reference}</td>
      <td>${data[i].ultimos_sismos_chile.scale}</td>
      <td>${data[i].ultimos_sismos_chile.local_time}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
  }

  let container = document.querySelector("#data");
  container.innerHTML = html;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en como accedes a los datos. Dentro del objeto de respuesta hay una propiedad llamada `ultimos_sismos_chile`, ese es el arreglo con los datos.

Modifiqué la función para que reciba ese arreglo:

```js
let url =
  "https://chilealerta.com/api/query/?user=demo&select=ultimos_sismos_chile";
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => mostrarData(data.ultimos_sismos_chile))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

const mostrarData = (data) => {
  let html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += `
    <tr>
      <td>${data[i].reference}</td>
      <td>${data[i].scale}</td>
      <td>${data[i].local_time}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
  }
  let container = document.querySelector("#data");
  container.innerHTML = html;
};
```

```html
<table id="data"></table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es ahi donde no recordaba como acceder .then((data) => mostrarData(data.ultimos_sismos_chile)) . ahora me quedo claro.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas haciendo el bucle for al objeto incorrecto, tienes que indicarle que tienes que mapear a `ultimos_sismos_chile` que esta dentro del objeto `data`.

Asi podra funcionar con los campos que indiques renderizar.

de esto:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

a esto

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.ultimos_sismos_chile.length; i++)
```

luego cuando estes construyendo las etiquetas HTML debes de cambiar a esto

```
<td>${data.ultimos_sismos_chile[i].reference}</td>
```

para que te de el resultado final algo asi.

```js
const url = "https://chilealerta.com/api/query/?user=demo&select=ultimos_sismos_chile";
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => mostrarData(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

const mostrarData = (data) => {
  let html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < data.ultimos_sismos_chile.length; i++) {
    html += `
    <tr>
      <td>${data.ultimos_sismos_chile[i].reference}</td>
      <td>${data.ultimos_sismos_chile[i].scale}</td>
      <td>${data.ultimos_sismos_chile[i].local_time}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
  }

  let container = document.querySelector("#data");
  container.innerHTML = html;
};
```

```html
<table id="data">

  </table>
```

Saludos.